# How to get html table data value dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, ajax

my aspx.cs code:

```
string studentid = dr["StudentId"].ToString();
        string studentname = dr["studentName"].ToString();
        Response.Write("<tr id = 'studentid' onclick = 'passValuesToInput(this)' >");
        Response.Write("<td id = 'sid' >");
        Response.Write(studentid);
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>");
        Response.Write(studentname);
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>");
        Response.Write("<img src = 'Edit-icon.png' height='20' width='20' >");
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>");
        Response.Write("<img src = 'ic_delete_48px-128.png' height='20' width='20'>");
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("</tr>");
    }
```

JavaScript function code:

```
function passValuesToInput(x){
alert(x.innerHTML);
document.getElementById("tbId").value = document.getElementById("sid").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("tbId").readOnly = true;
}
```

Whichever be the row I clicked on, It's passing only 1st row 1st element to textbox whose id = tbId. 
Help me out with suggestions.
I want to pass row's 1st cell to textbox whenever use clicks on edit or delete images.

Comment: *id* should be unique . so use class="sid"  and you need to get the currently clicked row cell instead of getting value form *id* .   x.cells[0].innerHTML;

Comment: Mohith are you comfortable to use jquery instead of javascript?

Comment: No, only JavaScript/Ajax is allowed. @AbhishekMaurya

Comment: Thank you @JYoThI

Comment: glad to help you @MohithKovela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**document.getElementById("sid")** will always return you the innerHTML of first cell, because **id** should be unique for each element, and therefore getElementById will pick the first element having that id.
If your **sid** is always going to be the first cell then you can try below code :

```
function passValuesToInput(x){
alert(x.innerHTML);
document.getElementById("tbId").value = x.cells[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementById("tbId").readOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: Working. :) I know why it is always returning fist row's value but couldn't resolve it. Thank you

Comment: My pleasure.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to pass unique ID for the row otherwise it will always pick the first one. You can try something like this:

```
string studentid = dr["StudentId"].ToString();
    string studentname = dr["studentName"].ToString();
    Response.Write(String.Format("<tr id = '{0}' onclick = 'passValuesToInput({0})' >",studentid ));
    Response.Write("<td id = 'sid' >");
    Response.Write(studentid);
    Response.Write("</td>");
    Response.Write("<td>");
    Response.Write(studentname);
    Response.Write("</td>");
    Response.Write("<td>");
    Response.Write("<img src = 'Edit-icon.png' height='20' width='20' >");
    Response.Write("</td>");
    Response.Write("<td>");
    Response.Write("<img src = 'ic_delete_48px-128.png' height='20' width='20'>");
    Response.Write("</td>");
    Response.Write("</tr>");
}
```

Then javascript can be written as:

```
function passValuesToInput(x){
 var elm = {};
 var elms = document.getElementById(x).getElementsByTagName("*");
 for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    if (elms[i].id === 'sid') {
        elm = elms[i];
        break;
    }
 }
 document.getElementById("tbId").value = elm.value; //or use elm.innerHtml
 document.getElementById("tbId").readOnly = true;    
}
```